# Boolean in view is true but in controller false angularJS

Tags: angularjs, scope, parent

In parent scope (external one which wrap entire webapp) I define boolean variable if you're logged in.

```
$localForage.getItem('authorization')
    .then(function(authData) {
            if(authData) {
                $scope.authentication.isAuth = true;
                //token is added in http interceptor
            } else {
                $scope.authentication.isAuth = false;
            }
        }, function(){
            console.log("error with getting authorization localForage after refresh");
        }
    );
```

It is basically working correct. Now I can build UI basing on this boolean with `ng-if="$parent.authentication.isAuth"`. I also can display true/false like so `<p>{{$parent.authentication.isAuth}}</p>` in view and it is also working correct.

In one controller I want to use this boolean inside controller not in view. So I do `if($scope.authentication.isAuth){` or `if($scope.$parent.authentication.isAuth){` (I tried both) and this condition go to else even when `<p>{{$parent.authentication.isAuth}}</p>` in view of controller where I'm using this condition display true.

So it

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <p>{{$parent.authentication.isAuth}}</p>
</div>
```

display *true* in paragraph and within controller named `ctrl` this condition `if($scope.authentication.isAuth){` go to else... Why such weird behaviour?

```
if($scope.authentication.isAuth){
    console.log($scope.authentication.isAuth);
    console.log('true');
} else {
    console.log($scope.authentication.isAuth);
    console.log('false');
}
```

And it `console.log` false and "false" string.

Comment: Does it really matter what code is within else? Ok. I edit.

Comment: You are printing the same value inside both conditions, how do you say it goes to the else part?

Comment: Because it console out false not true

Comment: I tried it and it is consoling false and "false" string now, take a look.

Comment: console.log(typeof $scope.authentication.isAuth); return boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you set the value async (`$localForage.getItem('authorization').then ...)`, it will be first `false`, then it might be set to `true` after the async operation has finished. Your view updates the value accordingly - everytime it changes - that's why you say it shows `true` in the view. It will be first `false` there, and after a few milliseconds will change to `true`. You don't neccessarily see that, but it still happens. The `console.log` is run before that async change happens, and as the `if > else` only runs once, it will only log the variable's state before it has been set to `true`.

Comment: In this scenerio $watch for boolean change will not hurt my app performance?